# java reflection: pass a value from the calling class but not as parameter

Tags: java, reflection

I have written a java class A with Method 'm' which I am loading dynamically in my program by reading A.class from the disk and using `defineclass` to `recreate` the class. Then I am invoking m in A.class from Main function of my program using `m.invoke(instance of A)`. The Method does not take any parameters. Can I "somehow" read a variable defined in the Main function of my program from inside m once it has been invoked?

Comment: You can only alter a local variable by passing a value and you can only get local variable by having the method return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Local variables are not accessible through reflection. You might hack around this limitation by setting an environment variable or writing the value out to a file and reading that file within `m`. In Java 8, you may also be interested in [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), which are capable of accessing local variables (though not a replacement for reflection).

Comment: Lambda functions can only obtain copies of local variables in Java.  In the JVM they are like any other class and must have all their values passed to them.